# How should I improve the bounty question of asking for photographs of different points of interests?

Tags: discussion

How should I improve the bounty question of asking for photographs of different points of interests (so that I get an answer)?

[What is a point of interest in a photograph and where is it lacking in this candle picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20927/what-is-a-point-of-interest-in-a-photograph-and-where-is-it-lacking-in-this-cand)

Is the bounty question not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's clear. It's just that you're asking for a considerable amount of work, especially to illustrate the concept perfectly. I have the plan of adding some examples to my answer, but I just haven't had the time.

Comment: Oh, I thought finding the photographs is the most easiest thing a peson can do. I didn't expect anyone to "shoot" photos, I thought people will just link something to flickr etc. The photographs there are actually important to show the concept clearly.